# jQuery YouTube TubePlayer Plugin-Play video inside my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using jQuery YouTube TubePlayer Plugin to play video from youtube.

I am able to play the YouTube video. But the plugin generates an iframe seperatly and plays the video inside it. But I need the video to be play inside my div. My HTML code looks something like this

```
<div class="youtube-player-container" id="youtube-player-container">
<div id="playvideo">
   <a onclick="playVideo('923ATOKI234','abc');">
      <img alt="Story No01" src="/images/Story1.jpg" />
   </a>
</div>
</div>
```

When user click on the thumbnail image an iframe is generated below and video is played. Is it possible to play the video within **playvideo** div itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is their any other way to play the YouTube video with video id inside a div.

Comment: YouTube videos play within an `iframe`. When you say "generated below", do you mean that the `iframe` is generated within `<div id="playvideo">` which should be the case, or outside of both `<div>`s? Do show us the code of function `playVideo()` and any other relevant, DOM related javascript statements.